# In Texas Holdem, who wins when community cards are five clubs, ace high? Only one of the five players is holding a club

Tags: texas-hold-em

TH community cards are a flush, ace high, clubs.
Who wins?
This happened yesterday. The winning hand was awarded the player with the highest card, any suit. But is this correct?  One of the 5 players held a club.  Only one.  Should the win have gone to that player?

Comment: The short answer is: if the club held by the player was higher than the lowest club on the board, the player wins. Otherwise, it's a split pot between all players in the hand. For example, if the board is AK984, all clubs, then the player wins if his club is a 5 or higher but not if it's a 3 or 2.

Answer (score -1):

In Texas Hold'em poker, the winner is determined by who has the best five-card hand according to the standard poker hand rankings. In the scenario you described, where the community cards form a flush (all five cards are clubs, with the highest being an ace), the winner is determined by the best five-card hand that can be made using any combination of the community cards and the players' hole cards.

Comment: This seems nonsensical. All TH hands are determined by the best five card combination available across the board and player's hand, the fact the board has a flush itself doesn't change that, and if it did, it is irrelevant what the player's hand contains.